# Getting totals in R for a 2x2x2 contingency table

Tags: r

I have data with 3 binary variables of the following form:

```
     A  B  C
     1  1  1
     1  0  0
     0  1  0
     .  .  .
     .  .  .
```

Suppose A is the factor that I am controlling.How would I get the frequencies of the 2x2 tables created from B and C for each level of A?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be: `with(dfrm, table(B,C, A))`?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df <- expand.grid(A = c(1,1,0), B = sample(0:1, 100, T), C = sample(0:1, 100, T))

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

This will keep the data in data frame (instead of a list using `table()`)

```
#Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#
#  A    B     C
#1 0 4700  5400
#2 1 9400 10800
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do as following.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,1,0),
                 B = c(1,0,1),
                 C = c(1,0,0))
df[] <- lapply(df, as.factor)

# split by levels of A
dfs <- split(df[,2:3], df$A)

# table for each level
lapply(dfs, table)

$`0`
C
B   0 1
0 0 0
1 1 0

$`1`
C
B   0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1
```